# How do we tell countable vs uncountable noun from OED?

Tags: word-usage

I am referring to the online OED, how can I tell whether a noun is countable or uncountable from the page? Thanks.

Comment: You can always use the [Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/rice), which tells you explicitly for each word. I believe the OED expects you to know for most words, and only says explicitly when they think there might be some uncertainty.

Comment: I remembered asking you about Mathematical notations before in ELU SE before, Prof Shor!

Comment: "Words can be countable or uncountable depending on the sense we have in mind when we use them" (Crystal 2011: 90). also http://english.stackexchange.com/a/70914/19046

Answer (score 1):

In the *OED* you may usually determine such things from the citations; but it's probably easier to follow Peter Shor's advice and consult the OALD.